# Password Regex (client side javascript)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, regex

I need a regex for the following criteria:

Atleast 7 alphanumeric characters with 1 special character

I used this:

```
^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$!%^&+=]).*$
```

It works fine if I type Password1! but doesnt work for PASSWORD1!.

Wont work for: Stmaryshsp1tal!

I am using the Jquery validation plugin where I specify the regex.

When I use a regular expression validator and specify the following regex:

```
^.*(?=.{7,})(?=(.*\W){1,}).*$
```

It works perfectly without any issues. When I set this regex in the Jquery validation I am using it doesnt work.

Please can someone shed some light on this? I want to understand why my first regex doesnt work.

Comment: £, … and π aren't good enough special characters for you?

Comment: FWIW, sometimes it just makes sense to run multiple regex tests as opposed to one massively complex one.

Comment: Do you want exactly 1 special character? Or at least 1?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't "work" for `PASSWORD1!`? It explicitly requires at least one lowercase letter, so if it doesn't match that, then it *does* work.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])
```

tries to match a digit and an alphanumeric character at the same place. Remember that `(?= ... )` does not glob anything.

What you want is probably:

```
^(?=.*\W)(?=(.*\w){7})
```

This is exactly the same as veryfying that your string both matches `^.*\W` (at least one special character) and `^(.*\w){7})` (7 alphanumeric characters. Note that it also matches if there are more.

Comment: Hi Benoit, thanks for your response but this is not working for me. I tried: regex:"^.*(?=.*\W)(?=(.*\w){7}).*$" but it doesnt seem to match the passwords I would expect it to such as Password1!

Comment: If you use regex_match and not regex_search, add `.*` at the end of the pattern (and remove `^`)

Comment: this is waht i use: $.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
                regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
            else if (regexp.global)
                regexp.lastIndex = 0;
            return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
        },
        "Input does not match complexity requirement"
 );

Answer (score 0):

As a good tool for quickly testing regular expressions I'd suggest http://regexpal.com/ (no relations ;) ). Sometimes simplifying your expression helps a lot.

<strike>Then you might want to try something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9@#$!%^&+=]{7,}$`</strike>

**Update 2** now including digits

`^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=!]).*$`

This matches:

- Stmarysh3sptal!, password1!, PASSWORD1P!!!!!!@#^^ASSWORD1, 122ss121a212!!

... but not:

- Password1, PASSWORD1PASSWORD1, PASSWORD!, Password!, 1221121212!! etc

Comment: Hi Brian, this regex matches password like "Password" I need them to use atleast 1 special character

Comment: I just saw that you want _at least_ one special character. Well so the above wont fit your needs I guess...

Comment: edited 2nd try, looks like it works (at least when I try it ;-) )

Comment: Hi Brian, that is great! Ok, I know I am moving the goal post a little, but can we modify it so that we make atleast 1 digit part of the criteria?

Comment: ok, so I took out that one question mark. Should work, doesn't it?

Comment: ... I guess you can also omit the first `^` and last `$` as long as you just want to match one single password at a time.
(If you would want to match several passwords seperated by spaces you would need something different again.)

Comment: hi Brian, removing the ? seems to have no effect. I also omitted the ^ and $ and it made no difference.

Comment: Are you sure? I edited the regex and the possible matches above. Before `Stmaryshsptal!` matched but now it doesn't. Add a digit `Stmarysh3sptal!` and it matches with the current expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\S*[@#$!%^&+=]+\S*(?<=\S{7,})
```

EDIT3: Ok, this is last edit ;).

This will match also other special characters. So if you wan't limit the number of valid characters change `\S` to range of all valid characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex , I think it can handle all possible combination..

```
^(?=.{7,})\w*[.@#$!%^&+=]+(\w*[.@#$!%^&+=]*)*$
```

here is the link for this regex, http://regexr.com?2tuh5

Answer (score 0):

The reason it matches `Password1!` but not `PASSWORD1!` is this clause:

```
(?=.*[a-z])
```

That requires at least one lowercase letter in the password. The pattern says that the password must be at least 7 characters long, and contain both uppercase and lowercase letters, at least one number, and at least one of `@#$!%^&+=`. `PASSWORD1!` fails because there are no lowercase letters in it.

The second pattern accepts `PASSWORD1!` because it's a far, far weaker password requirement. All it requires is that the password is 7+ characters and has at least one special character in it (other than `_`). The `{1,}` is unnecessary, by the way.

If I were you, I'd avoid weakening the password and just leave it as it is. If I wanted to allow all-lowercase or all-uppercase passwords for some reason, I'd simply change it to

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#$!%^&+=]).{7,}$
```

...thus not weakening the password requirements any more than I had to.